# Python: Create heatmap using string in col1 ('x_y') as coordinates?

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap

I want to create a **Heatmap** using Position (x_y) as the coordinates, and Value as the Colour intensity.

This is the dataframe:

```py
Position   Value
1_5      1
1_6     -1
1_7      0.5
2_5      6
2_6     -3
2_7     -5
```

A middle step could be creating a dataframe like so (the order of x, y is irrelevant):

```py
   1   2   
5  1   6 
6 -1  -3
7  0.5 -5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do `split` then `unstack`

```
df.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.Position.str.split('_').apply(tuple))
s=df.Value.unstack(0)
s
     1    2
5  1.0  6.0
6 -1.0 -3.0
7  0.5 -5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate dataframe can be obtained with:

```
(df.join(df.Position.str.split('_',expand=True).astype(float))
   .set_index([0,1])
   .Value.unstack(level=0)
)
```

Output:

```
0    1.0  2.0
1            
5.0  1.0  6.0
6.0 -1.0 -3.0
7.0  0.5 -5.0
```